# Angular ng-repeat on JSON data array

Tags: angularjs

Hi I'm a bit new to angular and trying to figure out how I could access a json key and iterate and print the values that are contained in an array. In my case below I'm trying to print the names along with their roles.

```
angular.module('employeeEarnestApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.employees = [ { id: 1, name: 'Alex', roles: ['admin','user','CEO'] },
  { id: 2, name: 'John', roles: ['developer','marketing'] },
  { id: 3, name: 'Kim', roles: ['sales','developer','CTO'] } ];
  });
```

How could I use ng-repeat to print out the roles in the array? I'd imagine it might be something like this below?

```
 <div class="container">
    <h2>My Employees</h2>
    <p class="form-group" ng-repeat="employee in employees">
     {{employee.id}} - {{employee.name}}
    <p class="form-group" ng-repeat="roles in {{employees.roles}}">
     {{roles}}
   </p>
   </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: nvm, ng-repeat, which is a directive, automatically evaluates the expression.

Answer (score 4):

Remove {{}} in ng-repeat, since ng-repeat automatically evaluates the expression, no need for {{}}.

```
 <div class="container">
    <h2>My Employees</h2>
    <p class="form-group" ng-repeat="employee in employees">
     {{employee.id}} - {{employee.name}}
    <p class="form-group" ng-repeat="role in employee.roles">
     {{role}}
   </p>
   </p>
 </div>
```

See, http://jsbin.com/hasuyewazi/1/edit

Comment: the second repeat should be ng-repeat='roles in employee.roles' - NOT employees.roles

Comment: Still not working for me - could there be something else I might be missing?

Comment: Missed " in employee.roles